# Kik.send to unique data-page

Tags: kik

I'm developing a KiK page that pulls in video content from our database and displays the items on data-page="home" of the KiK page. When you click on a particular video thumbnail, it properly takes you to the video's unique data-page. However, when sending the link to a friend with a KiK button, the link takes the friend back to the main page instead of the actual video's unique data-page so that they can watch the intended video.

Here is my current kik.send code for the button. Would I need to add in the optional 'data' field and pass something there?:

```
$(page).find('.kik-share').on('click', function () {
kik.send({
    title: '<?php echo $row["post_title"]; ?>',
    text: 'message description here',
    pic: '<?php echo $row["meta_value"]; ?>',
    big: true
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the unique id of the video in the data parameter. When the receiving user loads your home page you can then check kik.message to see if a unique video id is provided. If so automatically redirect the user to the given video.

Comment: Thank you! Great advice. And makes sense. I am unable to test things out at the moment, but I will give this a shot and will let know everything works. thanks again

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I was able to do more testing and your answer works like a charm. Thanks again!